# Onclicklistener not working on layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have a layout , if i press this layout another linear layout will come from the right (animation) and it will be previewed on it , but if i click on layout 2 , Onclicklistener wil not work ,

[image: This is before the animation]

[image: And this is after the animation]

But if set my first layout visibility to Gone , then the actions will be called on layout2,

i have used `layout2.bringToFront();` to move layout top , but still the action does not work

here is my complete source code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView btnHover;
LinearLayout layout1, layout2;

boolean isPageOpen = false;

Animation translateLeftAnim;
Animation translateRightAnim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_sample);

    btnHover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contact_row_icon);

    layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cell_view);
    layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cell_option_view);

    layout1.setOnClickListener(this);
    layout2.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnHover.setOnClickListener(this);

    translateLeftAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.slide_left);
    translateRightAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.slide_right);

    SlidingPageAnimationListener animListener = new SlidingPageAnimationListener();
    translateLeftAnim.setAnimationListener(animListener);
    translateRightAnim.setAnimationListener(animListener);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v == layout1) {

        layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        slideToLeft(layout2);
        layout2.bringToFront();


    } else if (v == btnHover) {
        layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        slideToRight(layout2);

    }else if (v==layout2){
        Log.d("tag", "clicked");
    }
}

private class SlidingPageAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (isPageOpen) {
            layout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            isPageOpen = false;
        } else {
            isPageOpen = true;
        }
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

}

// To animate view slide out from left to right
public void slideToRight(View view) {
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
            layout1.getWidth(), 0, 0, 0);
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    layout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

// To animate view slide out from right to left
public void slideToLeft(View view) {
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,
            -layout1.getWidth(), 0, 0);
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);


}
```

}

Comment: Your layout2 layout doesn't react to the listener right? Could you post some code where you asign a listener to layout2 and the code of the listener itself?

Comment: @TmKVU i have put the complete class

Comment: And why don't you want to hide the first layout? That does seem like a good solution. You could also try to request focus for the second layout with the requestFocus() function

Comment: @TmKVU i have put the layout2.requestFocus();  but still the onclick doesnt work on layout 2

Comment: you could also try to set the first layout's clickable property to false.

Comment: @TmKVU is thr anyway i can get clicked item id  ?? with the gestures ??

Comment: You could get the id with view.getId(); gestures are not measured with the OnClick. You could use an OnTouchListener to differ between different gestures.